# I am trying to compare the rows in both tables. And then display the category/categories that do not exist in line_items vs. product_class

Tags: sql

```
Select DISTINCT product_class.product_category
From line_items
    JOIN product
        on line_items.product_id = product.product_id
    JOIN product_class
        on product_class.product_class_id = product.product_class_id

Select DISTINCT product_category
from product_class
```

Comment: You should edit your question IN your question not in the title. And find a more appropriate title.

Answer (score 1):

Not too sure what you are actually after. I guess you want to have all category/categories from product_class that does not exists in line_items.

If so here is a solution

```
SELECT DISTINCT product_category FROM product_class WHERE product_class_id NOT IN (
SELECT DISTINCT product_class_id FROM product WHERE product_id in (
SELECT DISTINCT product_id FROM line_items))
```